# How to make bar frame invisible in R for ggplot geom_col function

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I am working on making a geom_col plot which has fill colours according to taxa categories, and x would be group and y be abundance, this is my code:

```
sig_counts_rowsample <- data.frame(t(sig_counts))%>%
        merge(.,anno_col,by=0)%>%
        pivot_longer(.,cols=2:(length(.)-1), names_to = "taxa", values_to = "abundance")
      options(scipen=10000)
      p<-ggplot(sig_counts_rowsample) +
        geom_col(aes(x=Group, y=abundance,fill=factor(taxa,levels=bar_sorting)),position = "position_stack(reverse = TRUE)")+
        scale_fill_discrete(name = "Taxa")
      output_name<-paste("Group_statistics/Sig_abundance",mtype,"barplot.svg",sep="_")
      ggsave(output_name,plot=p,device="svg",units="cm",width=35,height=18)
```

this is the what the data frame looks like:

```
> sig_counts_rowsample
# A tibble: 1,491 x 4
   Row.names Group taxa                                 abundance
   <I<chr>>  <fct> <chr>                                    <dbl>
 1 L1-0      L0    g__Desulfallas_s__gibsoniae                0  
 2 L1-0      L0    g__Streptococcus_s__thermophilus           0  
 3 L1-0      L0    g__Streptococcus_s__agalactiae             0  
 4 L1-0      L0    g__Streptococcus_s__acidominimus           0  
 5 L1-0      L0    g__Clostridium_s__cellulovorans          358. 
 6 L1-0      L0    g__Lactobacillus_s__reuteri               30.4
 7 L1-0      L0    g__Lactobacillus_s__sakei                 40.7
 8 L1-0      L0    g__Lactobacillus_s__alimentarius          49.6
 9 L1-0      L0    g__Hungateiclostridium_s__saccincola       0  
10 L1-0      L0    g__Corynebacterium_s__ammoniagenes        39.2
```

I made some modifications to sort the order of the filled colours and bars. this is my jpg output:

[image: ipg output]

However when I save it to svg format (like the code above) the bar frame would be really obvious and I want it to look the same as the jpg picture, how do I do that?

this is the screenshot of the svg output(becasue I cannot upload svg file here)

[image: svg output]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the white lines are simply the default white color. In that case adding `color=factor(taxa,levels=bar_sorting)`should work.

Good luck!